# Adapt non-parametric delegate to 2 params using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Hope it is possible:
I have a delegate like this:

```
delegate bool X();
```

I have e.g. 10 methods that fits this signature but one takes 2 paramaetrs. How could I use the same delegate for this one as well? I do not understand lambda expressions well but think it is possible.

Comment: do you mean that when you invoke `X()` you want it to run `Y(g,k)` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. Do you want your delegate to accept a method that takes 2 parameters? Or you want your parameterless delegate as an argument for a method that accepts a one with 2 parameters?

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully its more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, you just need to supply the arguments to the function you want to use.  You can't just call a function that requires arguments without any.

```
delegate bool ParameterlessToBool();                  // AKA: Func<bool>
delegate bool TwoParameterToBool(object a, object b); // AKA: Func<object, object, bool>

TwoParameterToBool objectsEqual = (a, b) => a.Equals(b);
object argument1 = 1;
object argument2 = 2;
ParameterlessToBool isEqual = () => objectsEqual(argument1, argument2);
bool result = isEqual(); // false
```

First, I declared two delegates to use in this example, `ParameterlessToBool` and `TwoParameterToBool`.  They are equivalent to the framework delegates `Func<bool>` and `Func<object, object, bool>` respectively.  You are not required to do this, it's just so I have something to work with in the example.

I used a two-parameter lambda to initialize the `objectsEqual` variable of type `TwoParameterToBool`.  It calls `Equals()` on the two parameters and returns the result.  I then initialized the two arguments that are required to be able to call this new function.  Then used a zero-parameter lambda to initialize `isEqual` variable of type `ParameterlessToBool`.  It calls the two-parameter function with the two arguments defined earlier and returns the result.  Then called the function to show how it's used.

Comment: So I always need to declare second delegate?

Comment: @lojol: No you don't.  These are just for the purposes of the example.  You just need some instance of the delegate you want to call and call it.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure..without second delegate how could I use the lambda expression?

Comment: @lojol: Ok I guess I misunderstood what you were asking.  What do you mean by "second delegate"?  Is there something you didn't understand about my description?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the oob delegates ?

- `Action<T>`
- `Funct<Tresult>`
- `Funct<Tin, Tresult>`
- `Funct<Tin1, Tin2, Tresult>`
- ...

For example, the following code may answer your question (If I understood it correctly) :

```
    public void MethodWithNoArgNoReturn()
    {

    }

    public int MethodWithNoArgWithReturn()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    public void MethodWith1ArgNoReturn(int i)
    { }

    public int MethodWith2ArgsWithReturn(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return 42;
    }

    void test()
    {
        var a1 = new Action(MethodWithNoArgNoReturn);
        a1();

        var f1 = new Func<int>(MethodWithNoArgWithReturn);
        var i1 = f1();

        var a2 = new Action<int>(MethodWith1ArgNoReturn);
        a2(43);

        var f2 = new Func<string, string, int>(MethodWith2ArgsWithReturn);
        var i2 = f2("test", "test");
    }
```